# Using Gradle to publish jars to MavenLocal

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm using Gradle to manage the build of a product using multiple eclipse projects.

Several of those projects use jar files that are not available from a central repository (like MavenCentral).

I'd like to have an eclipse project that I just place those jars into, and a build.gradle that will place those jar files into mavenLocal using the groupId, artifactId and version that I specify.

This way I can just add `mavenLocal()` to other projects and specify the dependency.

I have the following `build.gradle`:

---

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'myGroupId'
            artifactId 'myArtifact'
            version '1.2.3'
            from  <how to reference jar>
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried `file('myJar.jar')`, but that isn't accepted.  It appears that Gradle wants an artifact for the from value, but I can't seem to find how to specify a prebuilt jar file as that artifact.

Seems like it ought to be pretty simple, but I'm not finding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, 'from' can only accept `components.java` and `components.web`. To include a jar, use 'artifact', for example:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'myGroupId'
            artifactId 'myArtifact'
            version '1.2.3'
            artifact <path to file>
        }
    }
}
```

'artifact' can also accept output of archive tasks:

```
publishing {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                groupId 'myGroupId'
                artifactId 'myArtifact'
                version '1.2.3'
                artifact getlibrary
            }
        }
    }

task getlibrary(type:Jar){
    from <directory>
    classifier='lib'
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't see anything that indicated you could specify an artifact as a file location.  Works like a charm.